# How to Bake Lights

Tags: light, texture-baking

How does one bake lights and only the lights (no textures, shadows, etc.) in Blender 2.67b? I don't see anything that would indicate as to baking lights within the Bake Mode.

Comment: What would baking lights *do*?

Comment: Baking only works for Blender Internal Render not for Cycles. Baking for cycles is planned though.

Comment: An update for anyone reading this more recently, Cycles does have Baking at this point: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to do a [*Full Render* bake](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake). Textures and shadows can be disabled in the [*Shading* panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#Shading) of the render settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a few of the channels and mix them together later. For example, if you only want shading, you can bake shadows and AO, then mix them (using a multiply mix type) together in an image editor. If you wanted highlights as well, you could bake the specularity and mix it with the other two channels using the add mix type.